# Any finite-dimensional vector space is the dual space of another

Tags: linear-algebra

Any finite-dimensional vector space is the dual space of another?

This is from a true/false section in my book and the statement is supposedly true. I can't say I see the reasoning behind this and any hint/direction is greatly appreciated. My intuition says it has something to do with the isomorphic relationship between finite-dimensional vector spaces and their duals.

Edit: Here is the question as exactly phrased.

Every vector space is the dual of some other space? True or False . . .

I don't know whether or not they mean isomorphic, equal to, etc...

Comment: By "is," do you mean "is equal to" or "is isomorphic to"?

Comment: Perhaps you want to prove to yourself that every finite dimensional vector space is "reflexive". That is, the dual of the dual of $V$ is $V$ itself.

Comment: What is the name of the book?

Comment: Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel, Spence

Comment: It's false that any vector space is the dual of another. No dual has countably infinite dimension. The quote from the book doesn't seem to include the finite dimensional condition.

Comment: I stated above that its finite-dimensional. The directions include that assumption.

Comment: Then "is" is being used very loosely. The only possibility I see is considering isomorphism classes. For "equal to" the question moves out of the realm of mathematics and into that of philosophy.

Comment: I think they mean to say that given a space $V$ we have $V=(\mathcal(L),\mathbb(R))$ for some other space $W$?

Comment: You should have seen earlier in the book that the vector space is naturally isomorphic to the dual of its dual as in oxelmon's comment.

Comment: What do we mean by "naturally" isomorphic?

Comment: Loosely, It means that the isomorphism is defined without having to reference some basis. (More specifically - don't ask that question of a Category theorist if you don't want your eyes to cross before the explanation is done!). if $x \in V$, define $F_x \in V^{**}$ by $F_x(f) = f(x)$ for all $f \in V^*$. Then the map $V \to V^{**} \ :\: x \mapsto F_x$ is the natural isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

For a finite dimensional inner-product space $V$, we can define any linear functional $f \in V^{\ast}$ as $f(w) = \langle v,w\rangle$ for a unique $v \in V$, this is often written as $f = \langle v,-\rangle$. For example, given the basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ (the standard basis) we have the *dual basis*: $\{\pi_1,\dots,\pi_n\}$, where, if $w = w_1e_1 + \cdots w_ne_n$, then $\pi_j(w) = w_j$, so that if $v = v_1e_1 + \cdots + v_ne_n$ our linear functional $\langle v,-\rangle$ is: $v_1\pi_1 +\cdots + v_n\pi_n$ (we can add two linear functionals, and take scalar multiples of them using the operations of the underlying field $F$:

$(f+g)(v) = f(v) + g(v)\\
(cf)(v) = c(f(v)).)$

In the expression $f(w) = \langle v,w\rangle$, $f$ is the function, and $w$ is the variable, we might re-write this as $f = v^{\ast}$ ($f$ is clearly a linear functional "derived" from the vector $v$).

But if we pull a "switcheroo" (this is a technical term) letting $w$ be the function, and $v$ the variable, we can define an element of $(V^{\ast})^{\ast}$ like so:

$w^{\ast\ast}(v^{\ast}) = v^{\ast}(w)$.

The mapping $w \mapsto w^{\ast\ast}$ is a ($F$-linear) isomorphism. While describing $V^{\ast}$ forced us to choose a basis, and define a dual basis (to squeeze "numbers" (scalars) out of vectors, we usually need *coordinates*), the correspondence $w \mapsto w^{\ast\ast}$ is *basis-free*, which is what texts means by saying it is "canonical".